# Spring Restful API: send file with json data using multipart/form-data

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm building a restful API with spring and I'm trying to send a file with multipart/form-data using postman.

Here is my controller:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Object> create(
  @PathVariable Integer entityId,
  @Validated FormDataRequest formData
) {
  return new ApiResponseHandler(formData.getFile().getOriginalFilename(), HttpStatus.OK).response();
}
```

And here is the DTO:

```
@Data
public class FormDataRequest {
  private String name;

  @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
  private LocalDate startDate;
  
  private MultipartFile file;

  private List<EntryDTO> entries;
}
```

1. My first question is that I have to send "startDate" in camel case in my request for it to be serialized. I would prefer to be able to send it in Snake Case (start_date) so that it is consistent with the rest of my API and Jackson configuration. Any ideas?
2. Then, I have a serialization problem with the "entries" property. Here is the error:

> Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to
> required type 'java.util.List' for property 'entries'; nested
> exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of
> type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'EntryDTO' for property 'entries[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

I try to send a JSON in postman :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

for your first question you can use @JsonSetter("start_date") on your setter methode.

for your second querstion i usually use @RequestPart MultipartFile file , @RequestPart Employe forExample  , but i ve seen codes like yours that maps directly to an object ,i cant' really figure out the issue but you can maybe try an explicit mapping to your list with  ObjectMapper